# how to change TAG POS in .js file in iMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I spent a lot of time and I thought my code was right but somehow iMacros gives an error message

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line: 7 (Error code: 991)
```

I think, it is because of `POS={{n}}`

Basically, I want to extract 10 txt one by one and use it to locate the `HREF`, `EXTRACT` the `HREF` and `OPEN` it in a different `TAB` but the problem is that the `TAG POS` keeps changing.

Here is the code

```
var macro1= "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "VERSION BUILD=8530828 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 60" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n"; // I tried removing this part but that didn't help either
macro1 +=  "TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"itemLabel fcb" EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; //this is the part that i don't seem to get
macro1 +=  "SET TITLE {{!EXTRACT}}" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TITLE:"{{TITLE}}" EXTRACT=HREF" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "TAB OPEN" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "TAB T=2" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS";
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{

  iimSet("n",i);
  iimPlay(macro1);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some fixes which may help:

1. remove `<br>` from your code - you do not need this
2. `iimSet("n",i);` - replace `n` with different parameter name
3. use internal variable like `!var1` instead of `"title"`
4. replace

   ```
   TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"itemLabel fcb" EXTRACT=TXT
   ```

   with

   ```
   TAG POS={{qqq}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:itemLabel<SP>fcb EXTRACT=TXT
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Bestmacros  The problem was resolved as soon as I changed ATTR=CLASS:"itemLabel fcb" to ATTR=CLASS:itemLabel<SP>fcb

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
iimSet("n",i);
```

- i: javascript
- n: imacros with variable {{n}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `n` as iMacros variable with double curly braces like `{{n}}`.

This error message was due to `LINE 7` on your code. Replace this line

```
macro1 +=  "TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"itemLabel fcb" EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
```

with

```
macro1 +=  "TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:itemLabel<SP>fcb EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
```

also use `TAB CLOSE` before `TAB T=1`.

```
macro1 +=  "TAB CLOSE" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Single quotes Instead of Double quotes
for e.g.

```
macro1 +=  "VERSION BUILD=8530828 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
```

to this one

```
macro1 +=  'VERSION BUILD=8530828 RECORDER=FX' + '\n;'
```